# Focus box on the screen turning red on my canon 800D

Tags: canon

I'm very new to photography, I have a EOS 800D. Sometimes I try to take a picture, noticing the focus box on the screen is red not green which won't let me take a picture. Why is that?

Comment: Are you talking about the focusing screen seen through the viewfinder or the LCD screen on the back of the camera seen during Live View?

Comment: Related: [Why is my dSLR not taking pictures when the shutter button is fully pressed?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/97119/15871)

Comment: Also: [Why can't my SLR autofocus on certain parts of a scene?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12185/why-cant-my-slr-autofocus-on-certain-parts-of-a-scene)

Comment: Are you try to focus too close?

Answer (score 2):

In general, the reason therefor is, that the object you are trying to focus on is not in the focusing range, in which the lens on your camera is able to focus.